# In Vaykira 6:2, why does the word for hearth have 3 enlarged letters?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, aleph-bet-letters

In the parashat Tsav, Vayikra 6:2, "This is the law of the burnt offering, it is the burnt offering on ***the hearth***...". In some Torah scrolls at the end of the word for hearth, it has three enlarged letters, Qoof, Dalet and Hey. Why are only those letters enlarged but not the Mem or the Vav that proceed them?
They form the word ***"qiddah"/ cassia bark***, could that have anything to do with the explanation?

Comment: I've never seen a Torah like this. Where did you see it?

Comment: @DoubleAA I found this in an Interlinear Bible by Jay P. Green.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you have a small Mem in this verse, the Scribal notes say that as well. If the writer of the scroll you are looking at embellished, made big or stretched the other letters after the Mem that is just his art work.
R